# React-native TextInput different behaviour on Android platform

Tags: android, ios, react-native, compatibility

I’ve just started using `react-native`
My component renders `TextInput` like that:

```
 <TextInput
   value={this.state.time}
   editable={false}
   onTouchEnd={this.showTimePicker}
 />
```

I need to get rid of blinking text cursor but detect when users touches input.

As it turns out on `IOS` platform works fine but `Android` doesn’t fire `onTouchEnd` function.

Is it bug in `react-native`? or should I get used to differences like that?

Comment: there is no onTouch event in doc https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput

Comment: Yeah, you're right but on ios it works. Does it mean that ios implementation differ from Android?

Comment: If an element has onTouchEvent at ios and textinput is inherited from that maybe it can work but I am not sure. The point in my comment was there isn't an event like this so you shouldn't use it in both platforms.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!